# SQL: CASE - Don't Display Record WHERE NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been tasked with coming up with a means of translating the following data:

**FROM** dates saved in *[OccuredAtUtc]* that look like this:

```
2016-11-19 10:35:13.5790000
2016-12-21 12:16:58.5080000
2017-01-13 12:16:58.5080000
2017-01-13 12:16:58.5080000
2017-02-13 12:16:58.5080000
2017-03-13 12:16:58.5080000
2017-04-01 12:16:58.5080000
2017-04-02 18:11:53.3090000
.
.
.
```

**TO** Filter **only the last 3 months** of all records in format: **'yyyy-MM'**... // *I don't cout the current month !* (2017-04)

I have already written some code:

```
SELECT
    Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM') AS 'Temp', -- temporary column to show, how original dates look like
    CASE WHEN ( Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM') = Format((DATEADD(MM, -1, GETDATE())), 'yyyy-MM') ) THEN Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM')
         WHEN ( Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM') = Format((DATEADD(MM, -2, GETDATE())), 'yyyy-MM') ) THEN Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM')
         WHEN ( Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM') = Format((DATEADD(MM, -3, GETDATE())), 'yyyy-MM') ) THEN Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM')
         ELSE NULL
         END AS 'Time'
FROM @TABLE
WHERE ( 'Time' IS NOT NULL )
--WHERE ( [OccuredAtUtc] NOT LIKE '2017-04%' ) AND ( [OccuredAtUtc] NOT LIKE '2016-12%' ) AND ( [OccuredAtUtc] NOT LIKE '2016-11%' )
GROUP BY Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM')
ORDER BY [Time] ASC


>>>OUTPUT:


__Temp__|_Time__
2016-12 | NULL
2017-04 | NULL
2016-11 | NULL
2017-01 | 2017-01
2017-02 | 2017-02
2017-03 | 2017-03
```

> The [Temp] COLUMN is there only to show what data are behind the cells with NULL

**I need to get rid of all the lines, where is NULL in the [Time] column.** As you can see, my WHERE condition in the code is not working, it might be some issue with the format of data? I don't know why it doesn't listen to 'Time' :(

PS: It works, if I use the comented WHERE that filters manualy the months from [OccuredAtUtc] by list. But I can't change a query every month manualy by writing a list of suitable months

PS2: I dont want to use any @variable methods, because Datasets in SSRS cant work very well with them. A simple query that filters data of last 3 months, without the current month.

> Or is there a way how to say... Hey CASE, if the ELSE happens, dont
>   show the line?

Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: you cannot use `Time` in your `where`

Comment: And why parameters are the issue in SSRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to reference 'Time' column alias in the where clause.

Try a subquery or cte.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT
Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM') AS 'Temp', -- temporary column to show, how original dates look like
CASE WHEN ( Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM') = Format((DATEADD(MM, -1, GETDATE())), 'yyyy-MM') ) THEN Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM')
     WHEN ( Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM') = Format((DATEADD(MM, -2, GETDATE())), 'yyyy-MM') ) THEN Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM')
     WHEN ( Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM') = Format((DATEADD(MM, -3, GETDATE())), 'yyyy-MM') ) THEN Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM')
     ELSE NULL
     END AS 'Time'
FROM @TABLE
--WHERE ( 'Time' IS NOT NULL )
--WHERE ( [OccuredAtUtc] NOT LIKE '2017-04%' ) AND ( [OccuredAtUtc] NOT LIKE 
'2016-12%' ) AND ( [OccuredAtUtc] NOT LIKE '2016-11%' )
GROUP BY Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM'))s
WHERE Time IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [Time] ASC
```

This is because of SQL query order of operations:

```
1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause
```

The 'WHERE' clause is evaluated before the 'SELECT' clause.

Comment: You neglected to mention the syntax issue that is the root cause of his problem.  He can not use ' around a column name in a where clause.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. This is working perfectly fine. Thank you so much for help and explanation ! <3

Answer (score -2):

'Time' is a literal string that will never be null. Its line saying Where 'JoeC' Is Null. This is because you can not use ' around field names in a where clause.  You can use [Time], Time or "Time".

EDIT
You can not use an alias in a where clause.  You need to repeat the code or use a subquery / CTE:

```
With cteQry As
(
SELECT
    Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM') AS Temp, -- temporary column to show, how original dates look like
    CASE WHEN ( Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM') = Format((DATEADD(MM, -1, GETDATE())), 'yyyy-MM') ) THEN Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM')
         WHEN ( Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM') = Format((DATEADD(MM, -2, GETDATE())), 'yyyy-MM') ) THEN Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM')
         WHEN ( Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM') = Format((DATEADD(MM, -3, GETDATE())), 'yyyy-MM') ) THEN Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM')
         ELSE NULL
         END AS Time
FROM @TABLE
)
Select Temp From cteQry
WHERE Time IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY Temp
ORDER BY [Time] ASC
```

Comment: can he use alias in `where`?

Comment: Good point, I was focused on the reason he was not getting the correct rows.  My original post would have had an error.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: np, that happens xD